# Render different partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to render different partial views from the _Layout file depending on what function I'm in, controller-wise.

The partial view is in the right column of the website which is located in the _Layout like so:

```
<aside id="right">
@Html.Partial("RightPartial")
</aside>
```

What I want to do is render a different partial view depending on where I am.
If I'm in the Index view I might want to view news and in the About view I might want to view phone numbers or something.

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{
    string currentAction = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    string currentController = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
}
```

Now based on the values of those variables decide which partial to render. To avoid polluting the Layout I would write a custom HTML helper:

```
<aside id="right">
    @Html.RightPartial()
</aside>
```

which might look like this:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString RightPartial(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        var routeData = html.ViewContext.RouteData;
        string currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");

        if (currentAction == "Index")
        {
            return html.Partial("IndexPartialView");
        }
        else if (currentAction == "About")
        {
            return html.Partial("AboutPartialView");
        }

        return html.Partial("SomeDefaultPartialView");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should the "public static class HtmlExtensions" go?

Comment: Wherever you want. You could have an `Extensions` folder or whatever you feel right. It's just an extension method that you need to bring into scope in your view in order to be able to invoke it. Either add the namespace in which this class is defined as `@using` directive at the top of the view or add it to the `<namespaces>` section of your `~/Views/web.config` file and the custom helper will be available in all views.